# Qt read data from website

Tags: c++, qt, qwebelement

what library do I have to use to get data from website.

For example I have such a case:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div class = "MyClass"> 
    <div class = "MyClass2"> </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And how do I get the name of the second class(`Myclass2`), what method do I have to use? 
I just wanna mention that in c# it was very easy here is more complicated in my opinion.

I was using `QWebElement` class but I haven't found proper method.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QWebPage` class which provides an object to view and edit web documents. Using `QWebElement` you can access to DOM elements in a `QWebFrame` :

```
QWebPage page;
page.mainFrame()->load(url);

QWebFrame * frame = page.mainFrame();
QWebElement doc = frame->documentElement();
QWebElement body = doc.firstChild();
QWebElement first = body.firstChild();
QWebElement second = body.firstChild();

QString str = second.attribute("class");
```

Comment: Thx but can you tell me how to do it using for or foreach loop ? Imagine if there are about 10 such div's

Answer (score 0):

You can use QXmlStreamReader to access your Dokument too.

Example loop:

```
QXmlStreamReader xml;
...
while (!xml.atEnd()) {
      xml.readNext();
      ... // do processing
}
if (xml.hasError()) {
      ... // do error handling
}
```

A helpful Example:
[QXmlStream Bookmarks Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/xml-streambookmarks.html)